# Rails Delete Post with Tags or Comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tagging

I followed this guide on this website to add tagging to a post. I'm having an issue... http://www.sitepoint.com/tagging-scratch-rails/

Whenever I go to delete an post with tags i get this error:

[image]

Here is my code right here for the delete:

[image]

I'm still learning rails and I run into this issue whenever I have comments on a post and try to delete the post as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set referential integrity constraints on your db.

There are still taggs in table taggings which reference to the post that you want to delete.

You need to delete taggings first before you can delete post.

Comment: How would I add the foreign key constraints to my db with a migration? D:

Comment: Alternatively, in your Post class, change `has_many :taggings` to `has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy`.  This will clean up taggings tied to a post automatically when the post is deleted.

Comment: You can check the link https://robots.thoughtbot.com/referential-integrity-with-foreign-keys

Comment: Awesome, simple fix and great explanation! Thanks